# Getting comparing and sending images from and to WhatsApp

Tags: python, automation, whatsapp, face-recognition

I am currently working on a python project where users can send me their selfies, and I will compare their faces with my wedding images database. After the comparison, I will send them back all the images in which they appear, without using api.
I have written already the code which compare the image to the database, this is the code:

```
import face_recognition
import os
import time

def load_face_images(source_folder):
    known_encodings = []
    image_paths = []

    for filename in os.listdir(source_folder):
        image_path = os.path.join(source_folder, filename)
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_path)
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

        # Process all detected faces in the image
        for face_location in face_locations:
            face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, [face_location])[0]
            known_encodings.append(face_encoding)
            image_paths.append(image_path)

    return known_encodings, image_paths


def search_person_in_images(target_image, known_encodings, image_paths, tolerance=0.5):
    target_face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(target_image)
    target_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(target_image, target_face_locations)

    matching_image_paths = {}

    for i, face_encoding in enumerate(target_face_encodings):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_encodings, face_encoding, tolerance=tolerance)
        matching_image_paths[i] = [image_paths[j] for j, match in enumerate(matches) if match]

    return matching_image_paths

start_time = time.time()
source_folder = "faces"
known_encodings, image_paths = load_face_images(source_folder)

target_image_path = "image1.jpeg"
target_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(target_image_path)

matching_image_paths = search_person_in_images(target_image, known_encodings, image_paths)

num_matches = sum(len(paths) for paths in matching_image_paths.values())
print("Number of matching images:", num_matches)

end_time = time.time()
execution_time = end_time - start_time
print("Execution time:", execution_time, "seconds")
```

My question is how can I get automatically the image that the user sends me compare it to my database and send back in WhatsApp?
I don't want to use api I want to do it in a free way if possible

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the API, you should probably use a tool like [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/). There are a number of projects that use selenium and web whatsapp to send messages.